# Enviar mensagem pelo OneSignal a partir do Android

Tags: java, android, api

Galera o código abaixo serve para enviar uma mensagem push via OneSignal, ao rodar no NetBeans tudo funciona perfeitamente mas ao tentar rodar no android não obtive sucesso. Gostaria que me ajudassem, segue então os códigos:

Este código que funciona no NetBeans:
package javaapplication2;

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaApplication2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String titulo = "Esse é um bom título";
    String mensagem = "Uma excelente mensagem para você";

        enviarNotificacao(titulo, mensagem);
    }

    public static void enviarNotificacao(String mTitle, String mMensagem ){

   try {
   String jsonResponse;

   URL url = new URL("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   con.setUseCaches(false);
   con.setDoOutput(true);
   con.setDoInput(true);

   con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
   con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ZGJjMzI3Z....");
   con.setRequestMethod("POST");

   String strJsonBody = "{"
                      +   "\"app_id\": \"08603795-b086-4d1e-9030-1...\","
                      +   "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
                      +   "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"

                      +   "\"headings\": {\"en\": \""+ mTitle +"\"},"
                      +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \""+ mMensagem + "\"}"
                      + "}";


   System.out.println("strJsonBody:\n" + strJsonBody);

   byte[] sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
   con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

   OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
   outputStream.write(sendBytes);

   int httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
   System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

   if (  httpResponse >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
      && httpResponse < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
      jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
      scanner.close();
   }
   else {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
      jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
      scanner.close();
   }
   System.out.println("jsonResponse:\n" + jsonResponse);

} catch(Throwable t) {
   t.printStackTrace();
}
    }


}
```

Esse código é a minha tentativa no android:

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Notifications {

private String jsonResponse;

public void setNotification(String titulo, String mensagem) {

    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT > 8) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        //your codes here

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/Notifications");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 1");
        }
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 2");
        }
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ZGJjMzI3ZmMtYzFlMy00YTRjLWEyOTctYTY4YTUyNTE1MTY1");
        try {
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 3");
        }

        String strJsonBody = "{"
                + "\"app_id\": \"08603795-b086-4d1e-9030-122d4270c398\","
                + "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
                + "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
                + "\"headings\": {\"en\": \"" + titulo + "\"},"
                + "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"" + mensagem + "\"}"
                + "}";


        System.out.println("strJsonBody:\n" + strJsonBody);

        byte[] sendBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 4");
        }
        con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 5");
        }
        try {
            outputStream.write(sendBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 6");
        }

        int httpResponse = 0;
        try {
            httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Erro na notificacao", "Erro ao enviar 7");
        }
        System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

        System.out.println("jsonResponse:\n" + jsonResponse);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu também estava indo por esse caminho, mas esse código seria mais para o caso de um servidor em Java. 
Para o Android é muito mais simples, é só fazer isso e mais nada:

```
try {
    OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en':'Test Message'}, 'include_player_ids': ['" + userId + "']}"), null);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[SDK Android OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk)